# Multiple Numbers of var possible?

Tags: c#, icsharpcode

How can I add Multiple var in this code?

```
var trimChars = "ab";
```

sample I want to add:

```
"ab", "as", "Ab", "As"
```

is that possible?

further more heres some of my code:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
         {
    string Slb = lb.SelectedText.ToString();
             var trimChars = "ab";
             var trimmed = Slb.TrimStart(trimChars.ToCharArray());
             rtb.SelectedText = trimmed;

             lb.Hide();
         }
```

thanks in advance and sorry for this newbie question :) .more power!

Comment: I think you might misunderstand what your code is doing.  what are you expecting to happen with the trim?

Comment: i just want to add var for trimstart something like - var trimChars = "ab", "as", "Ab", "As"; but code was not working so i wonder how to do it for multipleway

Comment: if you are trying to "trim" the start if the start has "ab"  then TrimStart isn't what you want.  Currently if it start with "ba" it will also trim those characters off

Comment: you mean if i set ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST, all chars will gone?

Comment: yes, they will all go

Comment: ahh ok i understand now ... sorry for the noob question but your answer enlighten me . thanks guyz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove strings from the start you can use :-

```
public string RemoveFromStart(string s, IEnumerable<string> strings )
        {
            foreach (var x in strings.Where(s.StartsWith))
            {
                return s.Remove(0, x.Length);
            }
            return s;
        }
```

and use it like

```
var x = RemoveFromStart("ablah", new[] { "ab", "as", "Ab", "As" });
```

or with your code

```
var trimmed = RemoveFromStart(Slb, new string[] { "ab", "as", "Ab", "As" });
```

Comment: 1. The Non-genetic type 'system.collections.ienumerable' cannot be used with type arguments, 2. Only assignedment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be usedas a statement, 3. identifier expected

Comment: i just copy the code before the keyevents args then runs it sir .

Comment: hmmmmm what version of .NET?

Comment: The non-generic type 'System.Collections.Inumerable' cannot be used with type arguments . Pointing error to Inumerable<string>

Comment: oh, you need using using System.Collections.Generic;  at the top

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @KeithNicholas ... sir is there a way i can make all strings unique? i mean for example strings are "as" and "asd" then i type asdfg then assuming i choose asd but whatsthe outcome was dfg instead of fg only ... any suggestion how to do it sir?

Comment: making this every string unique? var trimmed = RemoveFromStart(Slb, new string[] { "as", "asd" });